# Initializing resources in Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, initialization, gunicorn

I'm following up on this post [where-in-flask-gunicorn-to-initialize-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260127/where-in-flask-gunicorn-to-initialize-application). 
Specifically, I'm looking for what is the best pattern of initializing a connection pool (REDIS in my example) inside a Flask-Gunicorn application. Relating to the above link, I can put a setup code. Having said that - for every worker in Gunicorn this code will re-run. Is this the proper strategy of working with connection pools? 
There's also the possibility of of using the preload_app configuration, but I do wish to maintain the convenient application reloading.

I think my question can be generalized to - "what is the best pattern in flask/gunicorn for having an initializing code running only once for all workers?" (something a-la singleton).

Thanks!

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213619/sharing-a-lock-between-gunicorn-workers