# where does initialization code go for large flask applications

Tags: python, flask

I am building a flask application to control GPIO on my raspberry pi. I am using the [larger application Flask structure](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/) because even though my app isn't huge I very much enjoy having everything in separate files.

One thing I am not sure about is how to go about importing RPi.GPIO so that circular/redundant imports don't occur. In [this tutorial](http://www.andygmb.com/flask_raspberry_pi_input/) GPIO is imported into what would be the `views.py` in my file structure. But the author also uses GPIO inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block for initialization code.

Where would the `if __name__ == "__main__"` initilization code go for my file structure? I was thinking putting it in `run.py` right before `app.run(debug=True)` but I am not sure if this is where it is typically placed.

Secondly, If I import GPIO into the place where my initialization code goes will I run into circular/redundant import problems if I also import it in views?

Comment: "best" in terms of what? Also, if you start a sentence with "secondly", then you're asking two questions, which should go in two separate posts.

Comment: "best" as in the standard area where people place initialization code.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22260176/2642204) help?

Answer (score 0):

If you look on github, you can see the convention is usually to do something like put main.py, or app.py to build app, then in another file such as run.py, uwsgi.py, server.py where app is imported in and ran.